# WPF Application - <Ellipse.InputBindings> - <MouseBinding>

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I am new to WPF Development and run into a problem Regarding Mouse Binding of an Ellipse which was created with Item Controls Trough Data Binding. This is the source code. My Problem is that the "CLoadModelFromDisk" Binding is not executed. In another context the Command works without any problems.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding JointsModelPartView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">            
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding posx1}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding posy1}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="Point">                       
            <Ellipse Fill="AntiqueWhite"
                     Stroke="Black"
                     Width="10"
                     Height="10"
                     Margin="-5,-5,5,5"   
                     >
            <Ellipse.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding 
                    Command="{Binding CLoadModelFromDisk}"
                    Gesture="LeftClick"  
                    />
            </Ellipse.InputBindings>
        </Ellipse>                            
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It would be really nice if somebody could help me with this problem.

This is the code for the context menu which does not work with your solution. Do you have any idea why?

```
<Ellipse.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ContextActionsView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
                                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RCommand}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Ellipse.ContextMenu>
```

I already tried to set the Relative Source to the Header and Command but that also does not worked.

Comment: In your DataTemplate, the DataContext will be the item displayed in the template -- one of the items in JointsModelPartView. Do those items have a property of type ICommand named CLoadModelFromDisk? Or is that a property of the parent viewmodel that owns JointsModelPartView?

Comment: It’s the property of the parent view Model. But i don’t know how to set the correct data context than.

Comment: Easy peasy. See answer.

Comment: Even with the DataContext. before the ContextActionView is does not work.

Comment: Ugh. Context menus in WPF are weird. You may have to give a reference to that ContextActionView  collection (it is a collection?) to the list items. you could also try giving the ItemsControl `x:Name="myItemsCtl"` then binding `ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ContextActionView, ElementName=myItemsCtl}"`

Comment: I got the contextmenu working now. But i found no solution to select the "Ellipse" like I could do with a List box. Is there any possibility to get the original Binding Object to Set the focus correct on the list? I found no way to inform the original data source which item is select because the “Ellipse” only knows that it is a UI Element but does not know where its position is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DataTemplate, the DataContext will be the item displayed in the template -- one of the items in JointsModelPartView. Do those items have a property of type ICommand named CLoadModelFromDisk?

My guess is that they don't, and CLoadModelFromDisk is a member of the same viewmodel as JointsModelPartView. In that case, you need to bind not to the list item, but to the parent viewmodel to which the property actually belongs. That'll be the DataContext of the ItemsControl -- it must be, since the ItemsControl is able to bind to JointsModelPartView.

Try this:

```
<MouseBinding 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.CLoadModelFromDisk, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
    Gesture="LeftClick"  
    />
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was the solution

Comment: I Have the same Problem with contextmenue for the Ellipse. There the Binding is not working an the discribed method also does not work.